# how to use define resource in init.pp or node.pp when define resource in individual file

Tags: class, puppet

How can I define some resource in other *.pp and how to use in init.pp ?

I wrote a module to test define like this ：

```
vsftpd
├── files
│   ├── test
│   │   ├── 1.txt
│   │   ├── 2.txt
│   │   ├── 3.txt
│   │   └── 4.txt
│   └── vsftpd.conf
├── manifests
│   ├── file.pp
│   ├── init.pp
│   ├── test.pp
│   └── user.pp
└── templates
```

I define 2 class  and a define resource to test ,without any define resource ,It runs well ,I also can define a resource and use it in init.pp like **vsftpd::createfile**

but if I define vsftpd::test in another file test.pp
    it just can't run,errors:
    **Could not find class ::vsftpd::test for agent.jayma.com on node agent.jayma.com**
    even I include ::vsftpd::test first,I googled a lot ,but find nothing

```
file.pp
------------------
class vsftpd::file{
  file{'test':
      ensure    => 'directory',
      path      => '/tmp/test/',
      source    => "puppet://puppet.jaymz.com/modules/vsftpd/test/",
      recurse   => true

  }

}
------------------------
user.pp
------------------------
class vsftpd::user{
  user{'ftp_jaymz':
     ensure     => present,
     uid        => '504',
     home       => '/home/ftp_jaymz',
     shell      => '/sbin/nologin',
     password   => '$1$svfAKdBu$c8MnfTtA.12Nny2131Vb/jhPTR3/',
     gid        => 'ftp',
  }
}
-----------------------------------
test.pp
-----------------------------------
define vsftpd::test ($name=$title,$content){
   file {'abc':
      path      => "/tmp/${name}_text.txt",
      content   => "this is a test ${content}"

   }

}
--------------------------------------
init.pp
-------------------------------------

 - class vsftpd {    package {'vsftpd':
        ensure     => installed,   }

      service {'vsftpd':
        ensure     =>running,
        subscribe  =>File["vsftpd.conf"],    }

      file {'vsftpd.conf':
         path      => '/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf',
         require   => Package["vsftpd"],
         source    => "puppet://broker.jaymz.com/modules/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf"
   }    include ::vsftpd::user   
   include ::vsftpd::file

      define
   vsftpd::createfile($name1=$title,$content1){
         file{"/tmp/$name1.txt":
             ensure => file,
             content => $content1,
             mode    => 0644,

         }


      }    vsftpd::createfile{'nick':
              content1     => "hi nick",    }

      vsftpd::createfile{'jaymz':
              content1     => "hi jaymz",    }

      include ::vsftpd::test   
   ::vsftd::test{'jaymz_test':
              content      =>"hi jaymz_test",    }

   }

----------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what file you need source from? 1.txt, 2.txt or others? If you need source from 1.txt, it should be changed

from

```
source    => "puppet://puppet.jaymz.com/modules/vsftpd/test/",
```

to

```
source    => "puppet://puppet.jaymz.com/modules/vsftpd/test/1.txt",
```

Comment: thanks ,I means that define a method in another file test.pp and how to use the method vsftpd::test in init.pp，I solved it ,just use it without any include